# Render views to the layout without refreshing the page cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, layout

I want load views from controllers to the default layout without refreshing the default layout content in my cakephp site.

```
 <div id="content" class="wrapper">
              <?=$content_for_layout;?>
          </div>
```

i am rendering views in to  
there is headers and footers in the content of the layout.
i don't want to refresh that content while rendering views to the layout from controllers.

Comment: You say you want some ajax so ? ....

Comment: Post some code or an example of what exactly you want & you tried so far?

Comment: yes, its better there is a common code for load all the view

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to update content of views.

For example you have id="content" in which you have view data, so update this div accoringly

For jQuery post request:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

For jQuery get request:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Update you div as $( ".content" ).html( data ); // data is your html code

In your controller action

check request type and render their respective view and exit.

Comment: need to set auto render as false in controller ?

Comment: Yes,,,$this->layout = false; $this->autoRender=false;