# url not changing when loading views to layout using ajax cakephp?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery, cakephp

```
 function viewContent(url){
       $.ajax({
             type: "post",  // Request method: post, get
             url: url, // URL to request
             success: function(response) {
                                  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = response;
                           },
                           error:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                  alert(textStatus);
                           }
          });
          return false;
}
```

i'm using this function load views to the default layout.

```
<li><?=$html->link(__('Users',true),'javascript:viewContent("view_users/")');?></li>
```

and i'm calling that function from links parsing appropriate url to the function. but when i clicking those links view is loading without any problem but browser URL not changing.

Comment: what i want to do is keep header and footer static and load other views without refreshing the page like this site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change url on ajax request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955430/change-url-on-ajax-request)

Comment: http://localhost/AutomobiQuiz/view_users

Answer (score 1):

In general URL does not get modified in ajax request.

Following post discuss a way.

[Change url on ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955430/change-url-on-ajax-request)

You can also get interest in below.

http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: what i want to do is keep header and footer static and load other views without refreshing the page like this site.

Answer (score 0):

you have asked one question 2 days ago `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836660/render-views-to-the-layout-without-refreshing-the-page-cakephp/20837687#20837687`

Now this....

Better solution for your problem is

```
Step 1: use caching for header & footer. 
Step 2: Do not use ajax to update view content.
Step 3: Use standard redirection for pages in order to maintain your links.

Note: use KISS(Keep it simple stupid) methodology
```

And last thing ask your problem at once, so that you can get better answers!

Comment: how to use caching for header & footer, header & footer is in the default layout.

Comment: Tell me more about your header and footer files like how you are creating them, for example you are using some heavy queries to create them or they are just html files? and if possible state your complete problem.